# Setting a cookie for "items per page"

Tags: php, cookies

I have a new form that allows for a user selection of "items per page" within results displayed using Adam's Pagination scheme. The selection is already passed via the pagination links to the next and previous pages. If I want to store the "items per page" (ipp) as a cookie and be able to recall that for other pages that use similar schemes, what is the best way to do that? Below is my form:

```
<form action="product_list_by_category_ipp.php" method="get" name="ippForm" id="ipp_changer" class="ipp_changer">
<label>
  #pp:</label>

<select name="ipp" style="display:inline!important;margin:4px;" onchange="document.forms['ipp_changer'].submit()"> 
<option value="<?php echo $ipp; ?>"><?php echo $_GET['ipp']; ?></option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="All">All</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="cat" value="<?php echo $product_category; ?>" />


</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

When `$_GET['ipp']` is set, store its value in a cookie via [`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).  On subsequent pages, check first if `$_GET['ipp']` is set, implying that the value is being changed, then check if the cookie `$_COOKIE['ipp']` is set if a new value was not passed in `$_GET`, and finally, supply a default value if neither was present.

Any time `$_GET['ipp']` is present, it will overwrite the existing cookie and be used until another `$_GET['ipp']` overwrites it.

```
// If the value was passed in $_GET and is an int or "All"...
if (isset($_GET['ipp']) && (ctype_digit($_GET['ipp']) || $_GET['ipp'] == 'All')) {
  // Store it in the cookie
  setcookie('ipp', $_GET['ipp']);
  // And save in a variable
  $ipp = $_GET['ipp'];
}
// Then check existing cookies
else if (isset($_COOKIE['ipp']) && (ctype_digit($_COOKIE['ipp']) || $_COOKIE['ipp'] == 'All')) {
  $ipp = $_COOKIE['ipp'];
}
// Finally use a default value if none was set
else {
  // Default to 3 for example:
  $ipp = 3;
}
```

Later in your markup, you only need to use the value `$ipp` since its source has already been resolved from `$_GET, $_COOKIE`, or a default value.  Since we validated it as an integer, there is no need for additional escaping via `htmlspecialchars()`.

```
<option value="<?php echo $ipp; ?>"><?php echo $ipp; ?></option>
```

If you really want to be strict and verify that `$_GET['ipp']` is exactly one of your supplied options, use `in_array()`.

```
// Make sure it's one of your allowed values...
if (isset($_GET['ipp']) && in_array($_GET['ipp'], array(5,15,20,25,'All')) {...}
```

Comment: The ctype_digit($_GET['ipp']) will be false if 'All' is selected. +1 for the comprehensive answer

Comment: Thanks. That works well. I added "$_GET['ipp'] = $_COOKIE['ipp'] after the else if, so it would set that, if not already set.

Comment: @DavidBarrow You should not need to do that. It is unwise ever to write to `$_GET`. Instead, `$ipp` gets populated based on `$_GET` or `$_COOKIE`. The rest of the script should only use `$ipp`.  Anyway, if this solves your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tickmark beside it, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I was getting a problem from people who hadn't been to that page before getting "divide by zero" errors, since $ipp wasn't set yet. I had to at least initialize $ipp = 5 before the other code above.

Comment: @DavidBarrow Can't quite see the problem since the posted code has no division. The point of my code above is to 1) prefer the value from $_GET 2) retrieve from $_COOKIE 3) failing both of the others, initialize `$ipp` to default. As long as it is placed before any other use of `$ipp`, the default value will always be set.

Comment: Thanks. I will see if I can isolate the problem further. The "ipp' code is first, but a few people were getting the "division by zero" error and a missing variable error, which I believed was from $ipp not being initialized the first time they visited the site. I may have mistyoed something or left out something small.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP

```
setcookie("ipp", VALUE);
```

To retrieve it

```
$_COOKIE["ipp"]
```